# revert error in solidity

Tags: solidity, revert

```
function transferOwnership(address _new) onlyOwner {
    address oldaddr = owner;
    owner = _new;
    TransferOwnership(oldaddr, owner);
```

message is

> revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
>   The constructor should be payable of you send value.

I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says you are trying to send some ether into the contract by invoking the function transferOwnership() ( I am assuming the name of your contract is also transferOwnership), and don't think you have a callback function either with payable modifier. add payable modifier to your function like below

```
function transferOwnership(address _new) onlyOwner payable public {
    address oldaddr = owner;
    owner = _new;
    TransferOwnership(oldaddr, owner);}
```